# WORDPRESS User specific access via ID to specific contact forms CFDB7

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to implement in the code a way to show specific contact forms data to a particular user via ID but I'm having difficulty finding which part of the code to add it to.

```
 $user_ID = get_current_user_id();  
 if  ( $user_ID == ('2') ) {
```

I'm currently inside the `admin-mainpage.php` within the plugin files. 
It's not as simple as I thought as it doesn't store the form names via db.
Any help would be appreciated.

[Forms-list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EykRu.png)

Comment: I think you're going to want to give a bit more information. What plugin for contact forms? You want advice on how to go about this? It sounds like maybe you want to build a shortcode plugin of your own for this logic. I'd leave core plugin files alone.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!! Please add more information for the plugin. Also, as Tom Woodward pointed out, DO NOT EDITED PLUGIN FILES. If you update the plugin you will lose all your updates.

Comment: Hi the plugin title is in the title of this post, Contact Forms CFDB7. It's a plugin to allow you to view and export any contact form data. The first page of the plugin admin displays a list of just the forms and a count next to it. I want to display only 1 of those forms in the table based on per logged in user. I have already switched off auto update for plugins.

Comment: While turning off autoupdating will keep your stuff from being overwritten, it's almost always bad path long term. Generally you want to get various updates for the plugin from the developer . . . things like security and bug fixes.

Comment: Yeah man, any ideas then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Contact Forms 7 is your plugin for the forms portion while CFDB7 is an accompanying plugin that writes the form submissions to the WP database.

**Get the Form ID**

There are a couple ways to get the form ID. It looks like the easiest path is to look at the shortcode that the CF7 creates. [You can see it in their documentation here](https://contactform7.com/admin-screen/). The code is something like `[contact-form-7 id="4" title="Foo"]` with id being the form ID (4 in this case).

**Show the Right Form to the Right Person**

Assuming you know the user ids and the related form ids you want to show them, you could write a very simple [shortcode plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) to display the right forms for the right people. It'd be something like this untested code below.

```
//[user-form-display]
function user_form_display( $atts ){
     $user_id = get_current_user_id();  
     if ($user_id == 2){
       echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="4" title="Foo"]');
      } else if ($user_id == 4){
       echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="88" title="Bar"]');
      }

}
add_shortcode( 'user-form-display', 'user_form_display' );
```

You could then put the shortcode in the regular post field and not edit either the CF7 plugin nor mess with the theme files.

You could also make the shortcode fancier and tie user ids to form ids directly in the shortcode arguments. That would take a bit more effort but is probably worth it.

**Getting the Form Data**
You could modify the `$args` to include form ids based on an association with a user id or multiple user ids. The form ids should be a field in that table. That's the example indicated below.

Alternately you could modify how the information is returned based on the same relationships by setting up the if/then statements in the `$data_value` lines. This is easier probably but messier in the long run.

```
function specfic_table_data()
    {
        global $wpdb;

        $user_id = get_current_user_id();

        if($user_id == 1){
          $form_ids = array(4,6);//only returns forms with id 4 and 6 when it's user w id 1
        }         

        $cfdb         = apply_filters( 'cfdb7_database', $wpdb );
        $data         = array();
        $table_name   = $cfdb->prefix.'db7_forms';


        $args = array(
            'post_type'=> 'wpcf7_contact_form',
            'order'    => 'ASC',
            'posts_per_page' => 10,
            'post__in'      => $form_ids,           
        );

        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
            $form_post_id = get_the_id();
            $totalItems   = $cfdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table_name WHERE form_post_id = $form_post_id");
            $title = get_the_title();
            $link  = "<a class='row-title' href=admin.php?page=cfdb7-list.php&fid=$form_post_id>%s</a>";
            $data_value['name']  = sprintf( $link, $title );
            $data_value['count'] = sprintf( $link, $totalItems );
            $data[] = $data_value;
        endwhile;

        var_dump($data);
    }
```

Comment: +1 to the shortcode - especially the fancier version to allow passing of the user ids and form ids to make it expandable.

Comment: This seems like a great method mate thank you but is this for only displaying the form on the frontend of the site? I have the user ID and the form ID correct, but i'd like the user to be able to see the form data and not the form itself hence me referring to the db plugin. It's so complicated

Comment: I understand now. I'll add some to the response above.

Comment: This is exactly what I've been trying to do Tom! That code I've messed about with all sorts in those 2 spots you've added comments and nothing seems to work. I can get it to echo a message if certain ID and that's working but to display just one column in the table is baffling me.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of the table data that cfdb7 is writing?

Comment: It's already attached on the original question (Forms-list) mate. It shows them as tables and then you click on each one and it takes you to the data. In that original image I just want the table to show one row specific to their ID. Thanks so much for your help in advance mate

Comment: Poorly phrased on my part. What I'd like to see is the raw db table view through Sequel Pro or something like that.

Comment: I have no forms yet submitted but here's the tables: https://imgur.com/1lud58U Pardon if i'm wrong but we are displaying the form names from contact form 7 in that first result before even fetching any table data from sql, which is fetched onclick from `$link  = "<a class='row-title' href=admin.php?page=cfdb7-list.php&fid=$form_post_id>%s</a>";

Comment: Ok, I broke down and installed the plugins as you've stuck with it this long. I've updated the post above with a functioning query. It still needs some work but should point the way.

Comment: @TomWoodward thank you so much for your help! I've made a couple of edits and it's working fantastic. https://imgur.com/oiHQMOO Again really appreciate the help :)